# Under what circumstances should an Async method support cancellation

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await, cancellation

I'm currently building an async enabled version of an existing API and I'm struggling to find any guidance on when it is a good idea to support cancellation. Some Async methods in the BCL do not have an overload which accepts a `CancellationToken` and I found this [MSDN article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis.aspx) which states

> it is not essential for all async methods to support cancellation

So, what conditions would make it worth supporting cancellation via a `CancellationToken`?

I'm leaning towards the following conditions:

- Any awaited method called also supports cancellation
- Any awaited method may take longer than n ms to execute
- The method implementation has one or more logical exit points (e.g. no side effects of quitting early)

Are those reasonable conditions? there any others?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is just my opinion, but I'd say that if the `async` methods you're calling *all* support cancellation, then yours should. In a similar vein, if you're creating an `await`able API over a naturally-asynchronous operation, then do your best to support cancellation (e.g., via `CancellationToken.Register`).

I'd also say that any (synchronous) CPU-bound method that could take a "long time" should observe a cancellation token periodically (`CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested`). "Long time" is relative, but as a rough guideline I'd say anything over half a second (on older hardware, not our 8-core dev machines ;).

In any other scenario, you're talking about a much less useful form of cancellation - specifically, the cancellation may take an arbitrary amount of time to take effect. E.g., if some `async` methods support it but others don't. I'm not sure how useful a cancellation token parameter would be in that case; you might want to put it in, but be sure to document its limitations.

Comment: So if my async method calls 3 other async methods and only 2 of them support cancellation, you don't think my method should support it too?

Comment: I'm saying that if all 3 do, then yours certainly should. If only 2 do, then the answer isn't as clear; you could put it in, but document it well. I'm not saying you *shouldn't*, just be aware that there is an arbitrary amount of time where your cancellation won't have any effect.